# Moving the user to the same place, after completing the form at the bottom of the page in Django

Tags: django, forms

After choosing the option, I want to transfer the user to the same place. Can I do it in Django without using JavaScript?

[Example Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Trpy9anK5M8&feature=youtu.be&fbclid=IwAR3QPVWPg_2jbxaFLwO7n6i60HjgOvgSzLNVVvZKaNDlnKs5C3x6snc9GcQ)

The user can not see whether he has completed the form correctly or not, it is misleading. It must scroll down the page again.

Comment: Without JS? Set an `id` on some element where you want to move the user to. Then set this `id` as a URL fragment on the form action, like: `<form action="/url/to/view/#elementID">`. The part after `#` is known as fragment. This will only work if you're not returning any redirects from your view. The browser will automatically scroll down to the element with the given `id`.

Comment: Thank you! if you add a large format answer, accept it as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an `id` on an element where you want to move the user to. Then set this `id` as a URL fragment on the form action, like: `<form action="/url/to/view/#elementID">`. The part after `#` is known as fragment.

When the page loads, the browser will read the element `id` from the URL fragment and automatically scroll down to the element.

This will only work if you're not returning any redirects from your view.